# AngularJS issue parsing json using $HTTP.JSONP

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, woocommerce, jsonp

I'm trying to fetch data from wooCommerce api in an angularjs application using `jsonp` method

```
$http.jsonp('http://pwoo.dev/wc-api/v2?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
.success(function ( data, status, headers, config ) {
    console.log(data, status, headers, config);
})
.error(function ( data, status, headers, config ) {
    console.log("Error", data, status, headers, config);
});
```

and in return it gives me this error in console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

and breaks the code in error block

> http://jsfiddle.net/zzlalani/5Lj46p69/

here is the live link from same type of api I used in fiddle above

> https://sergedenimes.com/wc-api/v2

I have validated the json online and its correct and valid in format, you check it here in fiddle's console in the following link

> https://jsfiddle.net/zzlalani/ru6kozxn/1/

**Update:**

Ok its not working for `jQuery.ajax` as well check the fiddle below where I have used simple jquery's `$.ajax` method with `dataType: "jsonp"`

> https://jsfiddle.net/zzlalani/zvreh2xp/2/

I don't understand where is the issue because in my above angular example a simple test.json with data

```
{
    "name": "zeeshan Lalani"
}
```

throws same error. What m'I missing here? How people in this world use `JSONP` examples ? :(

Comment: Your data is JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: @Quentin I cannot make changes to api server, what changes should I make to access data as `jsonp` because with normal `get` call i get those cross domain issues.

Comment: You need the cooperation of the server if you want to get around the security systems that block cross origin requests. Use a different server if you don't control that one.

Comment: @Quentin isn't it a valid `JSONP`? https://sergedenimes.com/wc-api/v2?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK

Comment: with this url it says `GET http://pwoo.dev/wc-api/v2?_jsonp=angular.callbacks._0?callback=JSON_CALLBACK `

Answer (score 0):

The `jsonp` content should be between a callback function like:

```
JSON_CALLBACK({"data":{"A":123,"B":true}})
```